# How can I tell if xfs_repair is stuck or still running?

Tags: linux, centos, xfs

I have a backup server with ~72TB of space.  Only about half of that is used.  Earlier in the week I got the following message and directly after the xfs filesystem was unmounted.

```
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: Filesystem dm-0: XFS internal error xfs_trans_cancel at line 1164 of file fs/xfs/xfs_trans.c.  Caller 0xffffffff883e54fe
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: 
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: 
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff883dfd95>] :xfs:xfs_trans_cancel+0x55/0xfa
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff883e54fe>] :xfs:xfs_mkdir+0x429/0x465
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff883ee399>] :xfs:xfs_vn_mknod+0x161/0x215
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff800ed95a>] vfs_mkdir+0xe3/0x152
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff800edf30>] sys_mkdirat+0xa3/0xe4
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff800a7f3f>] sys_futex+0x129/0x14a
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff8005ddf9>] error_exit+0x0/0x84
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel:  [<ffffffff8005d116>] system_call+0x7e/0x83
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: 
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: xfs_force_shutdown(dm-0,0x8) called from line 1165 of file fs/xfs/xfs_trans.c.  Return address = 0xffffffff883dfdae
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: Filesystem dm-0: Corruption of in-memory data detected.  Shutting down filesystem: dm-0
Mar 15 15:15:47 kernel: Please umount the filesystem, and rectify the problem(s)
Mar 15 15:15:57 kernel: Filesystem dm-0: xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
```

So I ran the following command starting four days ago:

```
xfs_repair -vv -o bhash=16384 -o ihash=16384 -o ag_stride=16 /dev/mapper/cdp1raid-cdp1raid
```

The extra `-o` options helped speed it up substantially and it outputs to a log file which did show progress, but for the past two days it's only shown the message:

```
rebuild AG headers and trees - 73 of 73 allocation groups done
```

I've looked at things like `strace`, `iostat`, `htop`, and `atop` to see if I could find out whether it's still progressing or if it's stuck but haven't seen anything that spells out what the process is doing.  From running `iostat -xd` I can see the `sdc`, `sdc1`, and `dm-0` listings counting down the `r/s`, `w/s`, and `rsec/s` values but am not sure if this really signifies anything.

ANY help or guidance on this would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Looking at strace - does the output change at all? If not it's stuck.

Comment: @tink - strace only shows the following output.  Only time it changes is every 15 minutes when it outputs to a log file.

Process 5603 attached with 7 threads - interrupt to quit
[pid  8972] futex(0xe47d4f8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  8976] futex(0x2b4cb8916ea8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  8973] futex(0xe47d4f8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  8975] futex(0xe47d4f8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  5603] futex(0xe47d4f8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  5604] rt_sigtimedwait([HUP ALRM],

Answer (score 1):

Some people on the internet tell that `-P` flag for `xfs_repair` helps to avoid such hangs (whns strace shows only `FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE` and nothing else). Man:

```
       -P     Disable prefetching of inode and directory blocks. Use this option if you find xfs_repair gets stuck and stops proceeding. Interrupting a stuck xfs_repair is safe.
```